# How to convert a javascript object with methods to JSON and back to object with methods?

Tags: javascript, json

I've tried for a couple hours to convert the following object to JSON string:

```
car = {

    go : function(){
        alert('accelerating');
    }

}
```

When I convert using JSON.stringify(car), it returns {}, because methods won't work with json strings. So I thought there must be some sort of hack for that.

My question is: What is the quickest way to transform this object into a string and then back to an object, keeping its methods?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Not possible: [If undefined, a function, or a symbol is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array). JSON.stringify can also just return undefined when passing in "pure" values like JSON.stringify(function(){}) or JSON.stringify(undefined).](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify/#Description)